# Remove all '\' from a string in C

Tags: c, string, parsing

I am trying to get rid of all `\` characters in a string in C. For example, if a string is `co\din\g` it should convert the string to `coding`.

So far I have the code

```
  for(i = 0; i < strlen(string); ++i){
    if(string[i] == '\'){

    }
  }
```

That looks to see if there is a backslash. I don't know how I would do to remove the backslash, however. My only idea is to set the next character equal to the current character, however, I don't know how changing the length of the string would work with memory.

Comment: You don't want to use `strlen` in your loop condition, that would walk the whole string on every iteration. Put the length in a variable instead.

Comment: Do you really want to remove all backslashes? Or do you want to interpret backslash escapes? In other words, if your string were `a\\b`, would the result be `ab` or `a\b`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works. Since you're only deleting characters, you can write back into the same string. At the end, the termination `'\0'` will move to a lower index, and the rest of the array will simply be ignored by `printf`. Also, `\` is the escape character, so to pass the `\` itself you must write `\\`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void nukechar(char s[], char c)
{
    size_t j = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        if (s[i] != c) {
            s[j] = s[i];
            ++j;
        }
    }
    s[j] = '\0';
}

int main(void)
{
    char s[200];
    while (fgets(s, 200, stdin) != NULL) {
        nukechar(s,'\\');
        printf("%s", s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char st[] = "co\\din\\g";
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; st[i] != '\0'; ++i)
        if (st[i] != '\\')
            st[k++] = st[i];
    st[k] = '\0';
    fputs(st, stdout);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice use of `st[i] != '\0'` to avoid a `strlen()` call.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to use a second string for the result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char result[100] = {'\0'}, string[] = "co\\din\\g";

    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < strlen(string); i++)
    {
        if(string[i] != '\\')
            result[j++] = string[i];
    }

    printf("%s %s\n", result, string);

    return 0;
}
```

**Result**

```
$ gcc main.c -o main.exe; ./main.exe;
coding co\din\g
```

**Note**

It is necessary to use double backslashes, `\\`, so the character following the backslash is not interpreted as an escape sequence.